# Mark out past events in Jevents?

Tags: joomla

I would like to add some style to past events in Jevents calendar. There is a CSS class `cal_td_dayshasevents` which marks the days which have events. Is there a way to add a CSS class to past events in Joomla Jevents module?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if there is a css file for the module, you can simple add the class like so:

```
cal_td_dayshasevents {
    //css goes here
}
```

If there isnt already a css file, create one in the module folder, add you css code, then in the **default.php**, embed the css file using the following:

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::root() . "modules/mod_jevents/style.css");
```

Note: Im not sure what the module for JEvents is called so make sure you change is accordingly int eh code above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to me I have to clarify the question which is: how to make Joomla add a specific class to past events in calendar? Adding style rules for an existent class in a calendar table is not a problem. My goal is to distinguish past and future events on the calendar page.